# How to Deploy angular 2 CLI project in ubuntu production server hosted locally

Tags: node.js, express, angular

Im am building a locally hosted ubuntu server. I want to deploy Angular 2 cli project on this server. im a newbie to angular 2. kindly help

Comment: Can you clarify what you've tried and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The following will build your project and take care of minification, etc...

```
ng build --prod
```

That will generate a folder called "dist" - you can simply take the contents of that and copy them to your /var/www (or whatever the root of your webserver is)